# How can I use a .bat file to make the computer sleep again whenever it wakes up unexpectedly?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, sleep, wake-up

[image: https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/623/22056481124_6cb41164ee_b.jpg] 
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
Wake Source Count - 1
Wake Source [0]

[image: https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/763/21680581753_ce45aa17a1_b.jpg]

Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
Wake Source Count - 0
(No Wake Source is shown)

If I press a key to wake my computer from the sleep mode, the result will be the one shown in screenshot 1. 
If the computer wakes up unexpectedly, the result will be the one shown in screenshot 2.
I have tried various methods, but there is actually no way to prevent the computer from waking up unexpectedly. 
The problem did not arise until I upgraded my Windows 7 to Windows 10 last month, so I think the problem lies in Windows 10 instead of my computer, to which no hardware changes have been made.
In Event Viewer, the events that happen when it wakes up unexpectedly are exactly the same as those that happen when it wakes up normally (i.e. I wake it manually) 
In Power settings, under Conditions, waking the computer to run the task has  been disabled. 
By means of Task Scheduler, a .bat file can be run automatically whenever the computer wakes up, whether unexpectedly or normally.
What commands can be used in the file so that the computer will automatically go to sleep again whenever it wakes up unexpectedly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
powercfg -lastwake | findstr /I /C:"Type:"
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo woken up by something
) else (
    echo woken up unexpectedly
)
```

In short, it just looks for `Type:` in the output of `powercfg -lastwake` and if it doesn't exist then assumes that the machine woke up unexpectedly.

If you want to actually make the machine go back to sleep then replace the second `echo` with the following:

```
powercfg -h off
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
powercfg -h on
```

Bear in mind that your computer could get into a loop where it wakes, runs this script, goes back to sleep, wakes, runs this script, goes back to sleep and so on and so on.

Comment: On my computer, `if %errorlevel% == 0` does not work, but `if errorlevel 0` does.

Comment: I have just tried it. When it wakes normally, the `Type:` will be 0 and 1. When it wakes unexpectedly, the `Type:` will also be 0 and 1. There are no differences. What can I do?

Comment: Why are you disabling and enabling hibernate? That seems totally unneeded?

Comment: No, I have deleted `powercfg -h off` and `powercfg -h on` and just use `rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0`. The problem is that the errorlevel of normal waking is the same as that of unexpected waking. I have tried `if errorlevel 2`, but that is not the result of both normal and unexpected waking.

Comment: @Tonny I found that if you don't disable hibernate first then `rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0` will hibernate the computer rather than put it to sleep. If there is a better way to do this then I'm all ears!

Comment: @Richard: According to MSDN you should call it as SetSuspendState(0,0,1).  The 2nd param doesn't actually do anything and the 3rd tell it to ignore future wake-events so the Task-scheduler can't wake it (e.g. to defrag/windowsupdate, etc.) I can confirm that the first param (hibernate true/false) seems to be flaky. On 3 different computers it invoked hibernate even when false. On 2 others only when set to 1. Seems to be due to drivers that don't play nice.

Comment: I have no problem putting it to sleep using `undll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0` alone. My problem is that there are no differences in errorlevel between normal waking and unexpected waking. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Richard: Can you help with the above-mentioned problem?

Comment: If the output is exactly the same irrespective of whether the machine was woken normally or not then my solution won't work. I would suggest a new question that specifically looks for a command that can show a difference and then change the `findstr` line in my answer to use that. Sorry I can't be much more help.